# How return frequency distributions as integers

Tags: python, nltk

I'm using FreqDist to get the number of occurrences of a word to appear in a corpora as its quite fast.  The issue is ftable is not returning answers as an integer that I need  to do some basic operations on.

```
words = brown.words()
content = [w for w in words if w.lower()]
ftable = nltk.FreqDist(content)
```

e.g:

```
percent = ftable[sing]/ftable[s])*100
```

I've tried things like ftable.N[sing] but no luck.

Thanks!

EDIT:  Also in comments.
The w.lower() is to lowercase the words in the corpora so that when I run a for loop against them I'm only comparing lowercase values as the ftable matches strings exactly.  as Hello != hello
if using Counter is it as fast?
Is there an easy way of lowering the case of the corpora/wordlist being searched?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for `collections.Counter`, not a frequency distribution:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> words = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b']
>>> Counter(words)
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 1})
```

Also, `[w for w in words if w.lower()]` might be a little slow. You could speed it up by using `filter(None, words)`.

Comment: the `w.lower()` in the original list-comp doesn't really do anything.  Perhaps OP was looking for `[w.lower() for w in words if w.strip()]`?

Comment: @mgilson: Maybe. I'm not sure.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just guessing too.  I just thought I'd leave a comment in the hopes that it would be helpful to OP.

Comment: the lower is to lowercase the words in the corpora so that when I run a for loop against them I'm only comparing lowercase values as the ftable matches strings exactly.
if using Counter is it as fast?
Is there an easy way of lowering the case of the corpora/wordlist being searched?